# How to test that an Angular directive runs a watch handler when its value changes

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which needs to re-evaluate when its value changes. The code is actually working fine, but I want to put in a test case to catch this and I can't seem to get the watch handler to run.

I'll provide a simplified example:

So this is the html that uses the directive - data.id is a property evaluated on the scope which could be updated and cause the directive to run its watch handler

```
<div my-directive="id=data.id"></div>
```

And here is the directive code

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("myDirective", function()
{
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            function execute(directiveValue) {
                /** run directive things **/
            }
            execute(attrs.myDirective);
            scope.$watch(attrs.myDirective, execute);
        }
    };
}]);
```

And this is the Jasmine test I am trying to get to pass - the spy is for a factory that would get called inside the execute() function and pass this new ID value along

```
describe("updating ID", function() {
        it("should re-evaluate directive", function() {
        scope.myID = "12345";
        element = $compile("<div my-directive='id=myID;'></div>")(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        scope.myID = "new ID";
        scope.$apply();
        var instances = spy.calls.mostRecent().args[2];

        expect(instances).toEqual(["new ID"]);
    });
});
```

My test fails with

```
    Expected [ '12345' ] to equal [ 'new ID' ].
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry, a problem with my simplifying stuff and a typo in the html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a scope.$watch function, after calling scope.$digest/$apply, you should just assert that that change your $watch method makes has been changed:

```
describe("updating ID", function() {
    it("should re-evaluate directive", function() {
        scope.myID = "12345";
        element = $compile("<div my-directive='id=myID;'></div>")(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        scope.myID = "new ID";
        scope.$digest();

        expect(whatever scope property your watch function changes).toEqual(your expectation);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working, I'm not sure entirely what the root of my issue was but I will post my code in case it helps anyone. I think it was more to do with the way the value that was being watched was being evaluated, as my watch handler was actually running but was being passed an invalid value

Directive:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("myDirective", function()
{
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            function execute(directiveValue) {
                /** run directive things **/
            }
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return attrs.myDirective;
            }, execute);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Test:

```
describe("updating ID", function() {
    scope.myID = "12345";
    compile("<div my-directive='id=myID;'></div>");

    spyOn(AuthCheck, "isAuthorised");
    scope.myID = "newID";
    scope.$digest();

    expect(AuthCheck.isAuthorised).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```